# Are there any HD cameras with Pan/Tilt/Zoom features supported in Linux?

Tags: linux, camera, hardware-rec

> ```
> Answered:
> ```
>
> [How to connect HDMI camera to Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/328317/how-to-connect-hdmi-camera-to-linux)

I have tried a few cameras such as the [Bullet HD](http://www.dogcamsport.co.uk/dogcam-bullet-hd-camera.html). I was never able to make it work in my CentOS, Fedora, I returned their product finally, it was a nightmare.

Therefore instead of risking for next failure I am looking for a definitive answer on this, so that no driver issues arise under Linux and finally allow me not to use Windows or Mac anymore.

Has anyone ever had success with making a very very good quality camera work in Linux, such as for example [this one](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-industrialcameras/cat-industrialcamerapantiltzoom/product-EVIHD3V/)?

Which HD cameras are there for Linux? There should be no driver issues and they should also allow me to perform pan/tilt/zoom actions using USB, Firewire or the S-Video interface.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic as your question is essentially a shopping recommendation (please read the [FAQ]).

Comment: @slhck Sounds like a very difficult, specialized buying question of the kind JeffAtwood likes (liked?) though. I'd prefer some more information by the user what he found out so far.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: how can i find the driver for this does not work: http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-industrialcameras/cat-industrialcamerapantiltzoom/product-EVIHD3V/

Comment: @Daniel Hm — you might be right. Still I don't know what the requirement really is. Stackfan, do you just want *any* HD camera to work or a remote-controllable?

Comment: @slhck: sorry it was not a shopping question. I mention the link i need to have this get detected by my box, which driver i have to use or how i can plug it in for test?

Comment: @slhck: pen-tilt-zoom + hd camera (remote is not required). I cant seems ot make anyone working.

Comment: If you want the device it's probably best to [contact Sony themselves](https://www.servicesplus.sel.sony.com/UnderMaintenance.aspx). It's a $3.500 piece of equipment, you gotta have some customer support for it.

Comment: So there are still a few details missing: How do you want to capture the video? Do you want to digitally capture it straight to the Linux machine? You know that a real video capture card might be better suited for this — you can hook any cameras to them.

Comment: @Daniel Beck I see what you are saying, and tend to agree this is specific enough to probably be worth keeping.  But "I want a good camera with Linux drivers" isn't all THAT specialized, so I guess we'll see what others think.  That's why it takes 5. :)

Comment: @slhck: i will. But its so strange in whole www.internet.com no where i can find this topic/subject with proper answer. IS there no camera which has pen-tilt-zoom + hd support and has drivers for to use in Linux?

Comment: @slhck: still which video capture card that really also supports under Linux? Mostly no body develop drivers, and it become so risky even to think about it.

Comment: See, we're a pretty "normal" computer user site. Even power users hardly ever get to use *$3k worth of HD remote controllable camera equipment for Linux* (just read the phrase one more time!). We can leave the question open and see if you get some responses. I'd be surprised though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps take a look at a few places like www.linux-drivers.org which offer hardware compatibility lists for various flavours of Linux.

At the site above, they also have a specific [USB Support, Webcams & Digital Cameras](http://www.linux-drivers.org/usb_webcams.html) section with tons of applicable info on what can and can't be used in Linux in that category.

If nothing else, perhaps that will lead you to some camera manufacturers that work with Linux, or a set of technologies known to work in/with Linux (so you know what to look for in a camera).

Otherwise, you may want (as slhck mentioned in his comment) to call the manufacturers of these high-end cameras you are looking at.   They should be able to let you know if their expensive products work with Linux, and if they can't tell you either way, don't buy from them. ;)

Comment: Often, especially in larger cities, there are local retailers of high-end video production equipment. They might know more about what is available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fantastic bit of Linux video surveillance/recording software called [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) and they have some hardware notes for cameras - this may help...

http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Compatibility_List