# How to connect HDMI camera to Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, centos, kernel

In fedora or centos linux is it possible to connect HDMI camera to HDMI capture device ( http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/ ). And get the video for playback from Linux? Or still there will be driver issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Probably](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/support/detail/?sid=3947&pid=4042&os=linux&leg=0)

> Download
>   Desktop Video 8.0.1 for Linux
>   Date Added: 13 May 2011
>   Size: 174.15 MB
>   If you can't find the answer to your question in our support material, please contact us via telephone or email. For technical support in the United States, please have your hardware details and software version ready then: Telephone +1 408 954 0500

...

```
Supported distributions
------------------------

This release has been tested on:

    * Ubuntu 8.04 Desktop
    * Ubuntu 8.10 Desktop
    * Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop/Server
    * Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04
    * Fedora Core 10/11/12 & 13 (See known issues)
    * OpenSUSE 11.1
    * CentOS 5

Several different package formats are supplied:

    * Native package (.deb) for Ubuntu and Debian based distribution.
    * Native package (.rpm) for RedHat and RedHat based distribution.
    * Native package (.rpm) for OpenSUSE and OpenSUSE based distribution.
    * Tarball for expert/custom installation (or re-packaging).
```

Comment: "Is there any other card which really works?" - I would ask that as a new question. "I have driver issues" - I would update the question with some details of the issues (and do say what Blackmagic support said when you reported the problem). "...which you recommended" - I didn't, I just showed where they said they supported Fedora 10-13 and Centos 5.